# Página em branco quando clicar em novo post no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-types

Tenho um post_type chamado Atas, quando clico para adicionar um novo post dentro desse pot_type aparece uma página em branco, conforme abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz algumas pesquisas e muitas pessoas disseram que poderia se tratar de algum plugin, mas não foi adicionado um novo plugin, já aumentei o memory limit no wp-config.php, mas não resolveu.

Comment: Coloque o código ou método que você esta usando pra gerar o post type para que alguém possa ajuda-lo

Comment: Ative o DEBUG no wp-config  e veja se tem algum erro.

Comment: Você usou algum plugin para criar este post_type, ou fez com código próprio?

Comment: O post_type eu gero por um plugin chamado Custom Post Type UI 1.5.2. Tem outros posts_types nesse site que estão funcionando normalmente.

Comment: e nos logs de erro nao tem nada la sobre isso?

Comment: Ativei o DEBUG, conforme o Kayo solicitou e apareceu esses erros:

https://prnt.sc/fj8zzt

Comment: Experimenta resetar os links permanentes

Comment: Se eu resetar  os links, depois quando for voltar, eles voltarão como era antes?  Porque os links estão com urls personalizadas para SEO

Comment: ao que parecevai ter que daruma boa revisada no seu codigo,os erros sao basicamente variaveis e constantes que nao existem ou nao foram iniciadas

Comment: Não posso garantir que voltarão à ser como antes, mas acredito que se vc apenas salvar novamente em "Configurações > Links Permanentes" sem alterar nada, isso dará um "refresh" nos permalinks que talvez possa ajudar à solucionar o problema. Não é garantido, mas em último caso se quiser tentar...

Comment: Corrigi os erros que apareceram no DEBUG e aparentemente resolveu. 
Agradeço a contribuição de todos.